# How to hide a Windows computer and Android phone in WIFI network?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, android

I am connected to a shared WIFI network, and I dont want any user will be able to see my devices.

When I run a WIFI scanner, or using the command arp -a, from a computer, I can see my (other) computer or Android phone.

I tried disabling sharing and computer visibility in Windows settings. Also made the network to Public.

But this does not help.
How can I disable discoverability completely by other devices in the same network?

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing two entirely different things: discoverability **does not imply** ability to connect. As long as you assume those are the same, it's impossible to give any useful advice.

> But this does not help. How can I disable discoverability completely by other devices in the same network?

More or less impossible unless the Wi-Fi network itself is reconfigured to allow that.

As long as two devices are in a single subnet, they *will* be able to talk directly at IP level, and this always implies answering ARP queries from any other device in that subnet.

Although it's possible to filter ARP packets in some operating systems (like on Linux with ebtables), it's not something you can do on Windows, and it's not as simple as disabling ARP outright – as you still have to answer *the router's* ARP queries.

If the Wi-Fi network is public, having the network's owner enable "Client isolation" would be the preferred option; that way the Wi-Fi access point wouldn't even deliver any packets from one client to another.

Generally, though, there is no harm in keeping ARP working; it does not imply anything about ability to connect (the Windows Firewall will block any other packet just fine). While it technically does reveal your MAC address, *merely being on the network* already reveals that to anyone who cares, so again disabling ARP wouldn't even solve that completely – enabling "MAC randomization" in your OS will be a much better general solution (Android and Windows both have that these days).

Comment: Why is it impossible to be undiscoverable? the computer need to be configured not to answer any packet originated in the local network except the one coming from the router.

Comment: @BestR- Limitation of how WiFi (802.11) clients and access points work.  What you want is not possible

Comment: @Ramhound Do you mean that it is happening before the firewall? and on ethernet is it possible?

Comment: @BestR: For ARP, because Windows does not have any features to perform packet filtering at that level; and for Wi-Fi in general, because phones and standard routers transmit in all directions, a device in "monitor mode" could easily gather MAC addresses of all nearby participants.

Comment: @BestR - In order to connect to an access point a client has to broadcast a request and like, an access point is also broadcasting, all this is done before any encryption comes into play.

Answer (score 2):

**Questions**

You forget to tell us *why* you want this, and that makes this probably an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). We cannot answer your question if we don't know why.

What do you mean with a "shared wifi network"? Is that your own wifi network, or maybe the school network, or a public wifi network like in a bar? Again, your question lacks many details.

**The solution**

I have an answer though. If you don't want that your devices are discoverable on a network that is shared with others, you have to setup your own network, only for your own laptop(s) and phone and other devices. You can do this with a portable wifi router.

**A portable wifi router**

You can buy a portable or travel router, like the [GL.iNet AXT1800](https://GL.iNet%20AXT1800%20(Slate%20AX)). I have this router, and I'll describe it here in short:

- USB-C powered, so you can use your laptop to power it
- It has a web interface like your home router, for administration and setup
- Dual wifi (working at the same time)

  - Connect your laptop and phone to the router via wifi
  - Connect the router to another wifi network
- Ethernet connection

  - Connect your laptop to the router directly
  - Connect the router to another network
  - This router only has one ethernet port, so the other connection has to use wifi
- Wifi extender: extend an existing wifi network (not what you want, but it has this functionality)
- Firewall: the router has a firewall, protecting you from external attacks. You should have a firewall on your laptop as well. Better safe than sorry.

Using this setup you created your own personal (wifi) network, and have the router connect to the public network. Of course, the router will now be discoverable by other devices on the network.

NB: TP-Link has a much cheaper router that can do this ([TL-WR902AC](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/tl-wr902ac/)), and it's smaller as well, and there are probably other brands that offer this.

**The downside**

Now you have this device that you have to carry around. It's not really big or heavy, but much bigger than your phone. If you want to use this for your phone alone, when not using the laptop, it will be a hassle. You will look a bit like a nerd from the 80s.

**Dataplan + phone as hotspot**

Another solution, easier, but probably not cheaper. Get a dataplan with many gigabytes, never connect to wifi, and use the phone as hotspot for your laptop. In some modern concrete buildings the connection over 4G/5G is crap, so it won't work there.

Answer (score 0):

WiFi can easily be sniffed. Fact of life and I do that here.

Assuming you have a Wireless Router in your residence, make sure the wireless router is secured (password) and does not allow remote access.   You may need to speak to the owner of the router.

Make sure your Wireless Profile password is difficult to hack (special characters, upper and lower case, numerals.

Make sure the Windows Login password is equally secure as above. Make sure the Android uses Face security login.

Windows should be set for a private NOT public network. Same for Android.

Do as above and hackers may knock on your network but will not get in. I have followed as above and never hacked.